# Android framework architecture HAL folder

Tags: android, android-source

What is difference in folders hardware/ device/ vendor/ framework/ from AOSP
I cannot understand what the rules/relation from the folders

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `hardware/`
  Before "Project Treble", vendors would put their implementations of the hardware layer in this directory. However, these should now be located in `vendor/<vendor>/interfaces/`.

  - `hardware/interfaces/`
    Contains the [hardware abstraction layer interface definition (HIDL)](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl), as well as some dummy implementations for the same.
  - `hardware/libhardware/`
    Contains the legacy hardware abstraction layer interface definition.
- `device/`
  Contains device configurations. A device is a mobile phone, a tablet, a VR headset, and so on. If you build Android you always have to specify which device you want to build.
- `vendor/`
  Contains software that is provided by a vendor and not by the AOSP.
  You will find the implementation of the hardware layer, vendor-specific services as well as framework extensions in this directory.
- `framework/`
  Contains the Android application framework.

Comment: Thanks your answer, that is what I need.